# /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1: No such file or directory in Linux tty mode

Tags: linux, authentication

I'm working on ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
Recently, when I opened a text file, I couldn't scroll, so I restarted my computer.
But there's an loop login problem.
So I accessed tty2 with ctrl+alt+f2 and tried to remove Xauthority after logging in there.
However, if I use commands such as sudo, apt-get, ls, etc. after logging in, I will get a /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1: No such file or directory error.
Only pwd and cd have checked the operation.

I try to used the `$sudo ln -s` command to fix the error that the ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 file is missing, but as expected, a no-such file or directory error occurred, and the `$ sudo apt-get update` or `$ sudo apt-get upgrade`also experiences the same error

Not just tty2, but tty3, 4, 5... I ran it on my back, but it showed the same phenomenon (tty1 doesn't seem to be connecting)
[Error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVgQu.jpg)

I think the ultimate reason for the loop login problem is because there is no ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 file.

Please give me a solution or hint for this problem. Thank you!

Comment: As this is not a programming problem it's not suitable for this site. You have likely had a corrupted file system. The easiest way to recover this is to boot into a recovery environment and attempt to restore the missing files.

Comment: I agree. Following stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic you might rather want to use another Stack Exchange Site (stackexchange.com/sites) to post your question. Maybe unix.stackexchange.com would be a fitting choice.

Comment: Looking at the uploaded display screen, which indicates an x86_64 kernel. It looks like the system packages have been overwritten by arm64 versions of the packages. Now you can use binfmt_misc and the package `qemu-user-static` to run binaries in this case, but I'd be considering a full reinstall at this point.